# JQuery id targeting with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to target an id element using a variable in jquery, like so:

```
var liked_artist = $('#js-helper-liked-artist').val();
var artist_id = $('#js-helper-artist-id').val();

var target = '#individual' + artist_id + '';

$(target).addClass('individual-heart-hover');
```

However, this is not targeting the id it should correctly.  Any ideas?  I've tried it without the empty string at the end as well.

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x individual-heart" id="individual-{{$artist->id}}"></i>
```

`individual-{{$artist->id}}` renders as individual-8

and artist_id is 8 (console.log shows this).

Comment: Your code looks fine can u do same in fiddle?

Comment: Can you add some html with the elements you use in your javascript?

Comment: make sure there is only one element with this id on page.

Comment: what artist_id output looks like ??

Comment: If you do this: `console.log($(target).length)` what is the output? If it is `0` the element does not exist, and your selector is wrong.

Comment: It is 0 when I run this to console, but doing console.log(target) prints the correct string.  Weird.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be  `var target = '#individual-' + artist_id + '';`? Unless it's a typo in your post, I think you are missing the dash.

Answer (score 0):

did you enclose your code in the document ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ....
});
```